# Separate double integrals with min/max

Tags: calculus, integration, maxima-minima

**Question:** Is it possible to separate integrals of multiple functions which contain min/max functions?

In my case in particular I have an integral in the following form:

$$
\begin{equation}
I = \iint_0^\infty f(x)g(y)\frac{min(x,y)^L}{max(x,y)^{L+1}}dxdy
\end{equation}
$$

Where L is some integer.  I have a numerical solver which seems to give reasonable results, but I would like to have a closed-form solution, if possible.  What I envision (if it is possible) is to have some sort of solution of the form:

$$
\begin{equation}
I = I_{x>y} + I_{x<y} + I_{x=y}
\end{equation}
$$

(I argue that since $x=y$ only in some small infinitesimal case, it can be neglected)

What I have tried:

**Attempt 1:** Solve indefinite

I tried to solve the *indefinite* cases where $x>y$, $x<y$ and $x=y$, then add them thus:

$$
\begin{equation}
I = I_{x>y} + I_{x<y}=\int_0^\infty f(x)x^{-L-1}dx\int_0^\infty g(y)y^Ldy +...
\end{equation}
$$

However this solution seems to deviate from the numerical one.  For L=0, it seems to be almost exactly a factor of 10, at L=1 it seems to be a factor of 2, etc.  (This solution is especially tempting as I have closed form solutions for all of the integrals).

**Attempt 2:** Change bounds of integration

In this attempt, I utilized the min/max to change the bounds of integration of each of the cases.  So for example when $x>y$, I only integrate $y$ from 0 to $x$, something like:

$$
\begin{equation}
I = I_{x>y} + I_{x<y}=\int_0^\infty f(x)x^{-L-1} \left(\int_0^x g(y)y^Ldy\right)dx + ...
\end{equation}
$$

This doesn't seem to correspond to the numerical solution, but also doesn't seem to be off by some clean factor like attempt 1.

**Attempt 3:** Add new bound of integration

In this attempt I again use the min/max to split the equation, but this time I add a new variable and integrate over all possible values of this new variable.  So for $x>y$ I integrate $y$ from 0 to $z$, then I integrate $x$ from $z$ to $\infty$, then I integrate $z$ from 0 to $\infty$.

$$
\begin{equation}
I = I_{x>y} + I_{x<y}=\int_0^\infty \left(\int_z^\infty f(x)x^{-L-1}dx\int_0^z g(y)y^Ldy\right)dz + ...
\end{equation}
$$

Again, this doesn't seem to correspond to the numerical solution, but also doesn't seem to be off by some nice clear factors like attempt 1.

Comment: Attempt 2 should yield the right result.

Comment: @RcnSc I'll double-check my attempt that, but in the meantime, do you have some basis for your assertion?

Comment: You haven't posted the entire computation but every step you have posted is legal. Perhaps you can post all of it and we can look into it together?

Comment: I redid Attempt 2, but starting from a new Python script and carefully redid everything and sure enough it worked (I was missing a term in the original).  What is it you mean that you need to know the form of f(x) and g(y) ?

Comment: I mostly wanted to see the other term of the integral to make sure there wasn't an oversight with the bounds. If you managed to make it match with your script then I assume it's all good.